# alert handling in ui automation iphone app unable to cancel the option

Tags: iphone

system.logElementTree();

var target = UIATarget.localTarget(); 
target.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
UIALogger.logDebug("There was an alert!");

target.onAlert.buttons()["No"].tap({x:164,y:278});
return false;
even though no option is clicked systen not performing any action
Can anyone please help me ...

Comment: Shouldn't you use alert.buttons() instead of target.onAlert.buttons() ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of BamboOS suggestion which loops through various positions, you can try this inside your onAlert function:

```
alert.tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.6}});
```

This tap targets the middle of the UIAAlert (x:0.5) and 60% from top to bottom (y:0.6). This works when there is only one button. You have multiple buttons, then you have to changed the value of x. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just published a blog post regarding UI Automation and dealing with alerts:
http://www.conduce.net/Blog.aspx?f=Automated-Test-of-iPad-Apps

Basically following alert handler worked for me:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert){   
   var name = alert.name();
   UIALogger.logMessage("alert "+name+" encountered");
   if(name == "errorAlert"){
       var positionX = 500;
       for(var positionY=300; positionY<600;positionY+=10){
           target.tap({x:positionX,y:positionY});
       }
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would either use the "cancelButton" or "defaultButton" methods when handling alerts.